# ComponentWillReceiveProps not getting invoked

Tags: reactjs

The code is as follows.

```
state = {
  showSection: false,
  selectedAccount: ''
};
```

The render method is defined as follows.

```
return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.selectAccount} className="btn btn-default">Select Account</button> 
        {
           this.state.showSection &&
               <div>
                 <AccountSelectionForm handleAccordionClick= 
                      {this.handleAccordionClick}
                      selectedAccount={this.state.selectedAccount}
                 />  
               </div>
        }
      </div>
      )
```

selectAccount Method is defined as follows.

```
  selectAccount = () => {
     this.setState({selectedAccount: 'A123'})
  }
```

> AccountSelectionFormComponent

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.selectedAccount) {
      this.setState({
        accountId: nextProps.selectedAccount
      });
    }
  }
```

When the button is clicked, selectedAccount value is changed. The prop value also gets changed, since this is passed in the props.

In the AccountSelectionForm component i have written the componentWillReceiveProps method to set the selectedAccount in the state.

My assumption was that this would invoke componentWillReceiveProps method since the prop is changed.
The problem is that the componentWillReceiveProps method is not invoked.

Questions:

Is this issue due to AccountSelectionForm still not rendered in DOM(this.state.showSection is still false).

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you give more code where you've written `componentWillReceiveProps`

Comment: I have modified the code